# TWA Android top url bar not hiding

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, twa

The bar with url does not disappear
I signed the application. 
I made a folder in public_html on my host with folder and file .well-known/assetlinks.json
a folder and a file must be placed in the application or application must be signed only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, goto **Tools** -> **App Links Assistant** -> **Open Digital Assets Links Generator**. From there, generate your digital assets file and upload the content generated to .well-known/assetlinks.json. Also, verify the SHA-256 key of the current build type of your app and the one uploaded to .well-known/assetlinks.json are same

Comment: I did this and it works when I install the application from my site directly. but when I upload the application to google play and install it again the top bar appears. Why?

Comment: Have you verified that the SHA key in the.well-known/assetlinks.json file and SHA key of your app downloaded from playstore same? As you might have Google App Signing enabled, the SHA key of the app might have changed.

Comment: yes, SHA key has changed. what should i do to stop changing?

Comment: You don't have to do anything to stop SHA key from being changing. Just put the final SHA key of the app that is there on playstore in your assetlinks.json file. The toolbar will not show up when you put your app on playstore then. But, it will be there on your debug app.

Comment: Thank you very much. you saved me!

Comment: ive done everything but it is weird because if run in emulator, it works ok, shows full screen. ir i deploy it to device, the toolbar still shows. i have no idea why.